# Cannot generate one web form by attaching two entities to it

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a 1 to n relationship so one `Brand` has many `Cars`. What I want to do is to create only one web form where all the fields from both of the entities get displayed. To do that I created a form type but I think I'm doing something wrong because I' getting error below when trying to print the form fields in twig. Could anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

**Error:**

```
Method "brand" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in CarBrandBundle:Default:both.html.twig at line 1
```

**Entities:**

```
class BrandEntity
{
   protected $name;
   protected $origin;
   //Followed by getters and setters
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BrandEntity", inversedBy="car")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @var object $brand
 */
protected $brand;
}

class CarEntity
{
   protected $model;
   protected $price;
   //Followed by getters and setters
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "CarEntity", mappedBy = "brand")
 * @var object $car
 */
protected $car;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->car = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addCar(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\CarEntity $car)
{
    $this->car[] = $car;

    return $this;
}

public function removeCar(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\CarEntity $car)
{
    $this->car->removeElement($car);
}
}
```

**Form Type:**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type;

use Car\BrandBundle\Entity\BrandEntity;
use Car\BrandBundle\Entity\CarEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BothType extends AbstractType
{
    public function builder(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('brand', new BrandEntity())
            ->add('car', new CarEntity())
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            //'data_class' => 'Car\BrandBundle\Entity\CarEntity',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'both';
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Controller;

use Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type\BothType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BothController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->getFrom();

        return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:Default:both.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Both', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    private function getFrom()
    {
        return $this->createForm(new BothType(), null,
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('bothCreate')));
    }
}
```

**Twig:**

```
{{ form_row(form.brand.name) }}
{{ form_row(form.brand.origin) }}
{{ form_row(form.car.model) }}
{{ form_row(form.car.price) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "car form" in which you need to choose a brand, then the other answer will be ok.

If what you want is a "brand form" in which you can add /edit/delete several cars, then you need to embed a Collection of Forms.

The cookbook answer is here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

To render a brand form containing a collection of car forms (1-n relationship):

The form types will look like this:

The brand type

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Form/Type/BrandType.php
//...
class BrandType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('description');

    $builder->add('cars', 'collection', array('type' => new CarType()));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\BrandBundle\Entity\Brand',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'brand';
}
}
```

The car type:

```
namespace Acme\CarBundle\Form\Car;

//...
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\CarBundle\Entity\Car',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'car';
}
}
```

Then the controller and the views just like in the cookbook. It's very powerful and easy in the end.

Comment: I made things simpler [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316726/using-two-entities-to-create-a-single-form).

Answer (score 0):

To add entities to a form you must use the entity field type: [from the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'property' => 'username',
));
```

> In this case, all User objects will be loaded from the database and rendered as either a select tag, a set or radio buttons or a series of checkboxes (this depends on the multiple and expanded values). If the entity object does not have a __toString() method the property option is needed.

Also please post the relationships.

Comment: Your example applies to only one field `username`. What if I have 100 fields in entity? Do I replicate it 100 times to get all fields? Question is updated above to show the relationships.

Comment: I made things simpler [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316726/using-two-entities-to-create-a-single-form)